# Segmentation fault with -O3 flag

Tags: c, optimization, clang, stack-overflow

Edit: I am really sorry if I have wasted time of your guys, I was running out of time when posting this problem. Here comes the code that I have done my best to minimize it

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum Error {
  ERROR_UNRESOLVED_NAME = 1,
  ERROR_CANNOT_OPEN_FILE,
  ERROR_NO_ARGV,
  ERROR_UNRECOGNIZED_SYMBOL,
  ERROR_UNCOMPLETED_SENTENCE,
  ERROR_RECURSIVE_SELF
};

struct _Piece;
typedef struct _Piece *(*PieceFunc)(struct _Piece *, void *);
struct _Piece {
  PieceFunc function;
  void *backpack;
};
typedef struct _Piece Piece;

Piece *piece_create(PieceFunc func, void *pack) {
  Piece *piece = malloc(sizeof(Piece));
  piece->function = func;
  piece->backpack = pack;
  return piece;
}

typedef struct _Record {
  char *name;
  int name_len;
  Piece *piece;
  struct _Record *previous;
} Record;

Record *record_register(Record *pre, char *name, int name_len, Piece *piece) {
  Record *record = malloc(sizeof(Record));
  record->name = name;
  record->name_len = name_len;
  record->piece = piece;
  record->previous = pre;
  return record;
}

typedef struct {
  char *file_name;
  char *source;
  int length;
  int current;
  int line;
  int column;
} Source;

Source *source_create(char *s, int len, char *file_name) {
  Source *source = malloc(sizeof(Source));
  source->source = s;
  source->file_name = file_name;
  source->length = len;
  source->current = 0;
  source->line = source->column = 1;
  return source;
}

Piece *apply(Piece *caller, Piece *callee) {
  return caller->function(callee, caller->backpack);
}

// Part 3, internals
Piece *internal_self(Piece *callee, void *backpack) {
  if (callee->function == internal_self) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "recursive `self` calling between two pieces\n"
            "piece 1 backpack: %p\n"
            "piece 2: %p backpack: %p",
            backpack, callee, callee->backpack);
    exit(ERROR_RECURSIVE_SELF);
  }
  return apply(callee, piece_create(internal_self, backpack));
}

Piece *internal_put(Piece *callee, void *backpack) {
  int *p_char = callee->backpack;
  putchar(*p_char);
  return piece_create(internal_self, NULL);
}

Source *main_create_source(char *file_name) {
  FILE *source_file = fopen(file_name, "r");
  if (!source_file) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file \"%s\"\n", file_name);
    exit(ERROR_CANNOT_OPEN_FILE);
  }

  char *source = NULL;
  int length = 0;
  while (true) {
    char *line = NULL;
    int line_len = 0;
    line_len = (int)getline(&line, (size_t *)&line_len, source_file);
    if (line_len < 0) {
      break;
    }
    if (source == NULL) {
      source = line;
    } else {
      source = realloc(source, sizeof(char) * (length + line_len + 1));
      strcat(source, line);
      // free(line);
    }
    length += line_len;
  }
  fclose(source_file);
  return source_create(source, length, file_name);
}

#define MAIN_REGISTER_INTERNAL(record, name, func)                             \
  record = record_register(record, name, sizeof(name) - 1,                     \
                           piece_create(func, NULL));                          \
  printf("%p %p\n", record, record->previous);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "please specify source file by command line argument\n");
    exit(ERROR_NO_ARGV);
  }

  Record *r = NULL;
  MAIN_REGISTER_INTERNAL(r, "put", internal_put);
  printf("main %p\n", r);

  Source *s = main_create_source(argv[1]);

  printf("main %p\n", r);
}
```

At first, the program crashed with a segmentation fault, I located the bad access code line, which have been deleted in this code demo. I figure out the original bug is that variable `r` in `main` would unexpected change after an unrelated calling to `main_create_source`, which would be demonstrated like this (save this code file as `foo.c`)

```
$ cc -O0 -g foo.c        
$ ./a.out futaba_test.ftb
0x7fc0024025b0 0x0
main 0x7fc0024025b0
main 0x7fc0024025b0
$ cc -O3 -g foo.c        
$ ./a.out futaba_test.ftb
0x7fe861c025b0 0x0
main 0x7fe861c025b0
main 0x7fe800000000
```

The behavior varied when changing optimization level. It has nothing todo with `EOF` since I have removed it, and in my opinion the memory for `strcat`'s destination is rich enough. Thanks for any help.

By the way if there is any requirement to point out the purpose of this snippet. This is an interpreter for a minimal language I am working on. It is able to evaluate small source code snippet at the time and this is the first time I have tried to build it with `-O3`. The bug will only disappear without any level optimization.

---

(The following is the original post and is able to be ignored.)

I have this [code file](https://github.com/lifta42/project-mitsuha/blob/dev/futaba.c). When compiling with `cc -O0 futaba.c`, and running it with `./a.out futaba_test.ftb`, the result will be

```
0x7fba60c025b0 0x0
0x7fba60c025e0 0x7fba60c025b0
0x7fba60c02610 0x7fba60c025e0
0x7fba60c02640 0x7fba60c02610
0x7fba60c02670 0x7fba60c02640
0x7fba60c026b0 0x7fba60c02670
0x7fba60c026d0 0x7fba60c026b0
0x7fba60c02700 0x7fba60c026d0
0x7fba60c02730 0x7fba60c02700
main 0x7fba60c02730
main 0x7fba60c02730
A%
```

(Zsh add the postfix `%`) everything is going well. But when compiling with `-O3` rather than `-O0`, than result will be

```
0x7f8f274025b0 0x0
0x7f8f274025e0 0x7f8f274025b0
0x7f8f27402610 0x7f8f274025e0
0x7f8f27402640 0x7f8f27402610
0x7f8f27402670 0x7f8f27402640
0x7f8f274026b0 0x7f8f27402670
0x7f8f274026d0 0x7f8f274026b0
0x7f8f27402700 0x7f8f274026d0
0x7f8f27402730 0x7f8f27402700
main 0x7f8f27402730
main 0x7f8f00000000
[1]    27811 segmentation fault  ./a.out futaba_test.ftb
```

The last two `main` line print different address, and the second one is not valid, which cause the stack overflow bug later in `record_resolve` function.

What is the problem?

Comment: Use a debugger to find the line causing the segfault.

Comment: *"What is the problem?"* 1/ You asked a question about a problem with some code which [we can't reproduce for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This gives me reason to "vote to close". 2/ You severly restricted the usefulness of your question by neglecting to explain the overall purpose or goal, the reason this program is being written. Perhaps this is an XY problem? We won't know until you give us some wholistic information. 3/ The answer to this question will almost certainly require comprehension of a book. Are you reading one? If so, which one?

Comment: Sorry, I won;t go through 440 lines of code for you. Use a debugger.

Comment: valgrind might be useful for this kind of problems.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. We're not going through hundreds of lines of code for a (probably) simple issue.

Comment: use GCC with `-Wall -Werror -fsanitize=undefined` and run with `valgrind`.

Comment: It `strcat`s out of bounds

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You really ought to check the return value of `realloc()` *before* you assign it to `source` - that's even worse than the unchecked `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of code, but here's at least a flag:

```
char source_fetch(Source *s) {
  return s->current == s->length ? EOF : s->source[s->current];
}
```

This forces `EOF` into a `char`, which is a very bad idea. That's why all standard C functions that can return `EOF` (like `getchar()` return `int`.

No idea what an optimizing compiler can make out of that, but once you factor in code that waits for `EOF` using that ... it's smelly.

Note: this is perhaps bad form as an answer; but it's pointing out a concrete problem with the code.

Also none of the heap allocations seems to have code looking for `NULL` being returned; that's a bit scary too.